# std::bitset<N>::count vs __builtin_popcount

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitset, std-bitset, hammingweight

Comparing the following two expressions

```
std::bitset<8>(5).count()
__builtin_popcount(5)
```

which one is better?

Comment: I've never heard of the second, so in that regard, the standard one. Also `std::bitset` guarantees portability and behaviour

Comment: _"which one is better?"_ According to what criteria ? As @Tas already mentioned, the standard one is portable.

Comment: What is "better"? Performance? Portability? Guaranteed behavior?

Comment: C++20 *finally* got around to providing `std::popcount`.  Compiling with `-march=x86-64-v2` or higher makes it a single instruction; various other ISAs have hardware popcount support.  (Which `std::bitset` should also use, in good libraries.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```cpp
int  __builtin_popcount(unsigned int);
```

is a built in function of GCC while `std::bitset<N>::count` is a C++ standard.

Both function do the same thing: return the number of bits that are set to `true`.

**What should you use?**

Always tend to use C++ standard's functions because other compilers don't support `__builtin_popcount` function.

**UPDATE**

If you take a look at the statistics made by Google Benchmark tool:

```cpp
#include <bitset>

static void GccBuiltInPopCount(benchmark::State& state) {
    for (auto _ : state) {
        __builtin_popcount(5);
    }
}

BENCHMARK(GccBuiltInPopCount);

static void StdBitsetCount(benchmark::State& state) {
    for (auto _ : state) {
        std::bitset<8>(5).count();
    }
}

BENCHMARK(StdBitsetCount);
```

with GCC 9.2 and flags `-std=c++2a -O3`, GCC built in function is 10% slower than the `std::bitset<N>::count()` function but, since the ASM output is the same for both function, the difference in benchmark could be due to other factors.

Comment: Considering that both sources produce the same code, see Denis' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60166085/1312382), I tend to assume the runtime difference resulting from other factors...

Comment: @Aconcagua actually, `-02` produces the same asm output but `-03` not

Comment: Tried both links above and changed to `-O3`, still both the same. Maybe not using the return values in your code has some influence on optimisations? I could imagine that the assembler call to `__popcountdi2` simply is discarded in second example as the value is not used anyway.

Comment: @Aconcagua yes, that could be the reason. Anyway, I will note that the difference in the benchmark could be due to other factors. Recommendation is still the same: `std::bitset<N>::count()`

Comment: Fully agree on the recommendation; I'd qualify the reasons for even stronger, though: Even *if* we would have discovered the extension to be faster, we should prefer the standard, unless we discover during *profiling* the standard to be a bottleneck in a time critical part of our application...

Comment: *"Both function do the same thing: return the number of bits that are set to true."* - Note that both functions are not equivalent. The two functions are only equivalent when `N == sizeof(unsigned int)` and you pass positive values.

Comment: This benchmark is pointless. If you turn compiler optimizations on, `__builtin_popcount(5)` is just going to be optimized out because it has no side effects and the result is unused. You're benchmarking nothing.

Answer (score 9):

According to godbolt, [bitset](https://godbolt.org/z/UpN8Qh) and [popcount](https://godbolt.org/z/C4tY8W) yields just the same asm output on latest g++. However, as mentioned in the comments, `__builtin_popcount` is an gcc extension and won't be available on neither other compilers nor other architectures than x86. Therefore, bitset option is clearly better.

Comment: I'd say that's the K.O. criterion for popcount already. But additionally, with popcount one is limited to unsigned int, i. e. usually 32 (sometimes even only 16) bits, whereas, since C++11, bitset accepts unsigned long long, allowing for (at least) 64 bits (OK, we could use bitshifts and multiple calls for popcount as well, but that's simply not as nice...).

Comment: `__builtin_popcount` isn't x86-specific.  If you compile without HW support for a popcount instruction (like x86 `popcnt` via `-march=x86-64-v2` or `-mpopcnt`, or baseline for AArch64), it compiles to a call to a libgcc helper function that uses a bithack.

Answer (score -1):

When you don’t know the value of N in `std::bitset<N>::count`, I think the second one is better

update:
you can try  [std::popcount](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount)

Comment: For runtime-determined bitset size, boost::dynamic_bitset is available, which also has a count method.